# Creating a range based on variables

Tags: variables, range

Here's what I'm trying to do:

A= 3

Rows("10:A").Insert

But I can't figure out how to assign a range based on a variable. A lot of the solutions i've found online seem rather complicated, is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't recognise what language you're using. You can edit your question to add it in your tags so it gets the proper attention.

Comment: Without at least identifying the language this is in, we can't even tell you if it's possible, much less how to do it...